# C++ Standard Library Portability

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, g++, portability

I work on large scale, multi platform, real time networked applications. The projects I work on lack any real use of containers or the Standard Library in general, no smart pointers or really any "modern" C++ language features. Lots of raw dynamically allocated arrays are common place.

I would very much like to start using the Standard Library and some of the C++11 spec, however, there are many people also working on my projects that are against because "STL / C++11 isn't as portable, we take a risk using it". We do run software on a wide variety of embedded systems as well as fully fledged Ubuntu/Windows/Mac OS systems.

So, to my question; what are the actual issues of portability with concern to the Standard Library and C++11? Is it just a case of having g++ past a certain version? Are there some platforms that have no support? Are compiled libraries required and if so, are they difficult to obtain/compile? Has anyone had serious issues being burnt by non-portable pure C++?

Comment: It is really down to the compilers available for the embedded platform. If your code has to run on some ancient 8-bit platform with a compiler written before standarization, then you could well run into portability issues. But if you have any vaguely recent G++ then you are pretty safe, at least WRT C++03. My experience is that it is just becoming too painful to support these old platforms, and "embedded" devices nowadays are pretty sophisticated computers.

Comment: http://kera.name/articles/2010/08/it-is-not-called-the-stl-mmkay/

Comment: Do you mean _code_ portability or _binary_ portability?

Comment: The term "STL" refers to an old SGI library, which was so good it got integrated into the C++ standard library. C++11 added "move" functionality to containers, but nothing major, mostly some move-capable overloads and new ways to bypass copies using moves. C++11 allows implementation of more efficient containers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Library support for the new C++11 Standard is pretty complete for either Visual C++ 2012, gcc >= 4.7 and Clang >= 3.1, apart from some concurrency stuff. Compiler support for all the individual language features is another matter. See this [link](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport) for an up to date overview of supported C++11 features.

For an in-depth analysis of C++ in an embedded/real-time environment, Scott Meyers's [presentation materials](http://www.artima.com/shop/effective_cpp_in_an_embedded_environment) are really great. It discusses costs of virtual functions, exception handling and templates, and much more. In particular, you might want to look at his analysis of C++ features such as heap allocations, runtime type information and exceptions, which have **indeterminate worst-case timing guarantees**, which matter for real-time systems.

It's those kind of issues and not portability that should be your major concern (if you care about your granny's pacemaker...)

Comment: I _think_ (and I'll admit that I'm basing my opinion mostly on hearsay) that most embedded systems use a compiler based on g++, clang or the EDF front end.  In which case, they should have no problem with language features.  The portability issues are more likely to arise on the larger machines&mdash;Sun CC (for Solaris) is quite behind the times, and I suspect the same is true of other truly proprietary compilers---I would certainly not use `auto` or lambdas if I thought I might have to port to a mainframe.

Answer (score 3):

Any compiler for C++ should support some version of the standard library. The standard library is part of C++. Not supporting it means the compiler is not a C++ compiler. I would be very surprised if any of the compilers you're using at the moment don't portably support the C++03 standard library, so there's no excuse there. Of course, the compiler will have to be have been updated since 2003, but unless you're compiling for some archaic system that is only supported by an archaic compiler, you'll have no problems.

As for C++11, support is pretty good at the moment. Both GCC and MSVC have a large portion of the C++11 standard library supported already. Again, if you're using the latest versions of these compilers and they support the systems you want to compile for, then there's no reason you can't use the subset of the C++11 standard library that they support - which is almost all of it.

C++ without the standard library just isn't C++. The language and library features go hand in hand.

There are lists of supported C++11 library features for [GCC's libstdc++](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011) and [MSVC 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx#sectionToggle9). I can't find anything similar for LLVM's libc++, but they do have a [clang c++11 support page](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html).

Comment: That VS C++0x status is way out of date.

Comment: @DeadMG Teaches me to not check my sources.

Answer (score 3):

The people you are talking to are confusing several different
issues.  C++11 isn't really portable today.  I don't think any
compiler supports it 100% (although I could be wrong); you can
get away with using large parts of it if (and only if) you limit
yourself to the most recent compilers on two or three platforms
(Windows and Linux, and probably Apple).  While these are the
most visible platforms, they represent but a small part of all
machines.  (If you're working on large scale networked
applications, Solaris will probably be important, and Sun CC.
Unless Sun have greatly changed since I last worked on it, that
means that there are even parts of C++03 that you can't count
on.)

The STL is a completely different issue.  It depends partially
on what you mean by the STL, but there is certainly no
portability problem today in using `std::vector`.  `locale`
might be problematic on a very few compilers (it was with Sun
CC—with both the Rogue Wave and the Stlport libraries),
and some of the algorithms, but for the most part, you can
pretty much count on all of C++03.

And in the end, what are the alternatives?  If you don't have
`std::vector`, you end up implementing something pretty much
like it.  If you're really worried about the presence of
`std::vector`, wrap it in your own class—if ever it's not
available (highly unlikely, unless you go back with a time
machine), just reimplement it, exactly like we did in the
pre-standard days.

Answer (score 0):

Use [STLPort](http://www.stlport.org/product.html) with your existing compiler, if it [supports it](http://www.stlport.org/doc/platforms.html). This is no more than a library of code, and you use other libraries without problem, right?

Answer (score 0):

Every permitted implementation-defined behaviour is listed in publicly available [standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf). There is next to nothing less portable in C+11 than in C++98.